# Retirar determinadas palavras com PHP do textarea

Tags: php

Como eu faria para que, dentro do texto pronto em um textarea, eu retirar determinadas palavras? Explico:

Tenho um formulário onde o textarea contém o seguinte texto:

```
<textarea name="Declaracao" id="summernote" class="form-control">
Declaro que o <strong><?php echo $nome; ?></strong> do setor <?php echo $setor; ?>,  trabalha na empresa <?php echo $empresa; ?> desde o dia <?php echo $data; ?>
</textarea>
```

Observe que trago do BD o nome, empresa e a data de admissão. Até aqui tudo bem, porém quero dar a liberdade do administrador alterar o texto e salvar como modelo.

Para isso pensei em pegar as informações do BD, limpar o textarea as informações que vem do BD e substituir por _________.

Mas como eu faria isso como PHP, partindo do princípio abaixo:

```
<?php
....
public function salvarModelo($idColaborador)
{
    $idColaborador = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$idColaborador);
    $sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM tb_colaborador WHERE IdColaborador = '".$idColaborador."';");
    $visualizar = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
    // Parei aqui
}
```

Comment: Não seria atribuir às variáveis a string `_______`, tipo: `$nome = "_______";`

Comment: Isso, só que quando o administrador alterar as informações do textarea e clicar em salvar como modelo, as informações adicionais nome, empresa e a data de admissão irão juntos e precisaria retirar essas informações antes de salvar o modelo do banco de dados, para quando ele acessar novamente essa área, aparecer automaticamente o novo modelo salvo, só que o nome, empresa e a data de admissão apareceriam como _________.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver. Vejam abaixo:

```
public function salvarModelo($idColaborador,$texto)
{
    $idColaborador = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$idColaborador);
    $sqlColaborador = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DataAdmissao,'%d/%m%Y') AS DataDeAdmissao FROM tb_colaborador WHERE IdColaborador = '".$idColaborador."';");
    $peColaborador = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlColaborador);
    $texto = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$texto);
    // Aqui coloco as informações que preciso buscar
    $array = array($peColaborador->Nome,$peColaborador->Empresa,$peColaborador->DataDeAdmissao);
   // Aqui faço a troca
   $string = str_replace($array, "____", $texto);
// Depois eu altero na tabela dos modelos
   mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE...");
   ..... 
}
```